# chrome profile could not be opened

Tags: google-chrome

I know this question appears to have been asked a million times but here goes...

Every time I open Google Chrome I get the error message

> Your profile could not be opened correctly...blah blah blah...

I've tried renaming the Default folder in

```
C:\Users\myUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\
```

I've tried deleting my user in chrome in the Settings page and logging back in again but nothing works. I've also reinstalled Chrome. When I sign in for some reason 3 extensions appear for some unknown reason. These addons weren't installed before this error happened.

I'm using Chrome 33 on Windows 7.

Comment: What are the three extensions? You might have something messing with your profile..

Comment: Google docs, chat undetected, avg safeguard

Answer (score 0):

<s>According to what is written [`here`](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/qMxWTALeZIQ%5B1-25-true%5D) problem seems to be caused by AVG</s>.

**Update 2**

1. Delete this folder `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`.
2. Open Chrome again.

If you have other profiles is preferable to delete them also.

Good luck!

Comment: I also just tried that with no luck. :(

Comment: @codedude look now.

Comment: I don't have AVG installed (I did about a year ago) nor can I seem to uninstall the extension since as soon as I sign in again it reinstalls it

Comment: @codedude however there is still something of avg installed on the computer? perhaps a toolbar, etc..

Comment: I've searched and can't find a thing.

Comment: @codedude updated the answer. See if you can eliminate the error. :-)

Comment: I found several folders in my \Appdata folder that corresponded to the plugins that were causing issues. I removed these and the plugins stopped trying to install themselves everytime I started Chrome. However, I still get about 6 "Profile could not be loaded" errors when I start Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Windows 7

Quit Google Chrome.
Open Computer.
Navigate to: C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default.
Delete the file named “Web Data”.
Start Google Chrome and the error should be gone.